# How to use in SoapUI refresh-token and token, to avoid 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, cookies, soapui

I need to take from Cookie both refresh-token and token to have access in application.
I am using SoapUI but I don't know how to pass those values.
Is not working with access token from header like Authorization: Bearer ${Properties#access_token}
Is a GET request

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in header Cookie as parameter and be sure that you have all the parameters from Request set in SoapUI